# Cassandra errors in logs, "Protocol exception with client networking: 2fe86256 invalid, unrecoverable CRC mismatch detected in frame header."

Tags: cassandra

We are seeing that Cassandra is generating immediate hint files after a restart and when going through the logging we see these CRC mismatch errors. Does anyone know why we are getting these?

Cassandra 4.0.5

```
ERROR [epollEventLoopGroup-5-15] 2022-11-18 16:08:25,390 NoSpamLogger.java:98 - 2fe86256 invalid, unrecoverable CRC mismatch detected in frame header. Read 3840, Computed 2312196
WARN  [epollEventLoopGroup-5-15] 2022-11-18 16:08:25,390 NoSpamLogger.java:95 - Protocol exception with client networking: 2fe86256 invalid, unrecoverable CRC mismatch detected in frame header. Read 3840, Computed 2312196
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was a time difference between the servers. We could also see that there were dropped messages (see below). The latency was basically the time difference between the servers.

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-11-18 17:33:52,380 MessagingMetrics.java:206 - MUTATION_REQ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 1910 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 7932 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-11-18 17:33:52,381 MessagingMetrics.java:206 - HINT_REQ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 3418 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 7620 ms
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!  Yes, time difference between nodes can cause some strange and unfortunate side-effects.